# CakePHP design url

Tags: url, cakephp-2.0

In my CakePHP environment I have a reuqest from a form with the method 'get'. When I send the form, the controller goes to

```
http://www.example.com/circles/index?searchterm=something
```

indstead of (cakestyle)

```
http://www.example.com/circles/index/searchterm:something
```

I don't know where I have to search for. Url redirecting is working properly. It's only if I send a request with the 'get' method.

Thank you for any help.

Ivo

Answer (score 0):

Its because of get request params goes with url as query string. If you want to get these value as named params. Then you have to do some jQuery work. Ex : you should change the submit method to post and get the field values on submit and make a url which you want then you can submit it through jQuery.

Comment: Thank you. I have read that in version 3.0 the named params no longer will exist. So I do it with the standard query sting thing.